# when piping to middleware I get error "createError(N/error)"],"cause":{"name":"SSS_MISSING_REQD_ARGUMENT","message":"create: Missing a required arg

Tags: php, http-post, netsuite, php-curl

When I post from from postman to netsuite directly I dont get an error but when I post via php curl I get the following error. Also if I change it from php:input to an internal referenced json setup it works.

ERROR : {"type":"error.SuiteScriptError","name":"SSS_MISSING_REQD_ARGUMENT","message":"create: Missing a required argument: type","stack":["createError(N/error)","post(/SuiteApps/create_saleso_extend.js:18)","createError(N/error)"],"cause":{"name":"SSS_MISSING_REQD_ARGUMENT","message":"create: Missing a required argument: type"},"id":"","notifyOff":false,"userFacing":true}

netsuite says the request they received is as follows:
Context : "{"entity": "14735","PurchaseOrder":"1234", "recordtype": "salesorder","item": [{"item": "311","quantity": "1"},{"item": "666","quantity": "1"}]}"

if I use postman to post directly to netsuite from postman I get the following and a success:
Context : {"entity":"24704","PurchaseOrder":"1234","recordtype":"salesorder","item":[{"item":"311","quantity":10,"amount":"1234.00"}]}

the only difference I see is that my php curl is adding .

My php code is as follows:

```
function sendOrderToNS($details) {
    $details = file_get_contents('php://input');
    $data_string = json_encode($details);
    $oauth_nonce = md5(mt_rand());
    $oauth_timestamp = time();
    $oauth_signature_method = 'HMAC-SHA256';
    $oauth_version = "1.0";

$base_string =
    "POST&" . urlencode(NETSUITE_URL) . "&" .
    urlencode(
        "deploy=" . NETSUITE_DEPLOY_ID
      . "&oauth_consumer_key=" . NETSUITE_CONSUMER_KEY
      . "&oauth_nonce=" . $oauth_nonce
      . "&oauth_signature_method=" . $oauth_signature_method
      . "&oauth_timestamp=" . $oauth_timestamp
      . "&oauth_token=" . NETSUITE_TOKEN_ID
      . "&oauth_version=" . $oauth_version
      . "&realm=" . NETSUITE_ACCOUNT
      . "&script=" . NETSUITE_SCRIPT_ID
    );
$sig_string = urlencode(NETSUITE_CONSUMER_SECRET) . '&' . urlencode(NETSUITE_TOKEN_SECRET);
$signature = base64_encode(hash_hmac("sha256", $base_string, $sig_string, true));

$auth_header = "OAuth "
    . 'oauth_signature="' . rawurlencode($signature) . '", '
    . 'oauth_version="' . rawurlencode($oauth_version) . '", '
    . 'oauth_nonce="' . rawurlencode($oauth_nonce) . '", '
    . 'oauth_signature_method="' . rawurlencode($oauth_signature_method) . '", '
    . 'oauth_consumer_key="' . rawurlencode(NETSUITE_CONSUMER_KEY) . '", '
    . 'oauth_token="' . rawurlencode(NETSUITE_TOKEN_ID) . '", '  
    . 'oauth_timestamp="' . rawurlencode($oauth_timestamp) . '", '
    . 'realm="' . rawurlencode(NETSUITE_ACCOUNT) .'"';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, NETSUITE_URL . '?&script=' . NETSUITE_SCRIPT_ID . '&deploy=' . NETSUITE_DEPLOY_ID . '&realm=' . NETSUITE_ACCOUNT);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
    'Authorization: ' . $auth_header,
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string)
]);

curl_exec($ch);
 $errors = curl_error($ch);
$response = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close($ch);
printf($errors);
printf($response);
}
sendOrderToNS($details);
```

Please assist thank you ^_^

Comment: That is a netsuite error not a communication error. It looks like you are communicating with a RESTLet that is throwing an error. You need to look at the RESTlet code to figure out what is going on.

Comment: @bknights if I attempt to use postman directly to the restlet it doesn't error with the same json values.... but if I use the same stuff using the php script and post to it. it throws that error. I have looked at what its receiving and its adding \'s all throughout the json post.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that since it's getting JSON as an input already via whatever source it is sending moots the need to do

```
$details = json_encode($data_string);
```

Removing and using `$details` directly works correctly.